# WSO2 Identity Server ciphertool.bat script throwing an InvalidPathException

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to run the `ciphertool.bat` script to encrypt strings in my WSO2 server.  I am running the script with the -Dconfigure flag and receiving a `InvalidPathException`

I have not edited the `ciphertool.bat` script, the `cipher-text.properties` or the `ciper-tool.properties` files.

I am running version 5.7.0 of WSO2 Identity Server on a Windows machine.

Command I am running and the console output

```
C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.7.0\bin>ciphertool.bat -Dconfigure

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
Using CARBON_HOME:   C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.7.0
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char 
<:> at index 45: C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.7.0\C:\Program 
Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.7.0\/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at org.wso2.ciphertool.utils.Utils.getConfigFilePath(Utils.java:98)
    at org.wso2.ciphertool.utils.Utils.setSystemProperties(Utils.java:289)
    at org.wso2.ciphertool.CipherTool.initialize(CipherTool.java:93)
    at org.wso2.ciphertool.CipherTool.main(CipherTool.java:52)
```

I expect that script would run without errors, especially if I haven't edited anything, but it's throwing this exception.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/wso2/cipher-tool/issues/36) has been identified and a PR has been sent [here](https://github.com/wso2/cipher-tool/pull/37). Unfortunately, it's not merged yet.

As a quick fix, you can follow the steps below.

1. clone the [repo](https://github.com/wso2/cipher-tool)
2. checkout to the branch "v1.0.0-wso2v8"
3. locally make the suggested fix in the [PR](https://github.com/wso2/cipher-tool/pull/37)
4. build the JAR
5. overwrite the `<IS_HOME>/lib/org.wso2.ciphertool-1.0.0-wso2v8.jar` with new JAR
6. try the ciphertool command

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I rebuilt the jar with the correct code and it worked.

Comment: Hi, can you upload the jar here as well

Answer (score 1):

You can give the location of the keystore file as below in `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` file

```
   <Location>${carbon.home}\repository\resources\security\wso2carbon.jks</Location>
```

(Please note the backslashes)

```
    <KeyStore>
        <!-- Keystore file location-->
        <Location>${carbon.home}\repository\resources\security\wso2carbon.jks</Location>
        <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
        <Type>JKS</Type>
        <!-- Keystore password-->
        <Password svns:secretAlias="Carbon.Security.KeyStore.Password">password</Password>
        <!-- Private Key alias-->
        <KeyAlias>wso2carbon</KeyAlias>
        <!-- Private Key password-->
        <KeyPassword svns:secretAlias="Carbon.Security.KeyStore.KeyPassword">password</KeyPassword>
    </KeyStore>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Throws the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 45: C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.7.0\C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.7.0\\repository\resources\security\wso2carbon.jks`

It seems like there may be an issue with the script.  It's trying to construct a path that has repeated directories.